# Creating a Macros File for Lyx

Tags: macros, lyx, preamble

I've created a set of macros in Lyx that I use continuously. I want to automatically include them in all my `.lyx` documents.

From what I've been reading in the forums, perhaps the most elegant way is to create a `.sty` file with my macros in it, save it in some folder, and then add stuff to the LaTeX preamble in the document settings of Lyx.

What I wasn't able to find is how to actually do the above, given that I'm not an experienced Tex/Lyx user. So my questions are:

1. How do you create and edit a `.sty` file?
2. What exactly do you need to type in the `.sty` file? Say I want the macro (I'm typing it as it appears in Lyx).

`\sequence{#1}:=(#1)^\infty _{n=1}`

I understand the above should be wrapped by some extra code (`\newcommand` etc.), but I don't know the precise format.

3. Where do you place your `.sty` file such that it can be included in all `*.lyx` documents globally? I'm a Windows user if it matters and I want to avoid adding it to every folder that contains a lyx document.
4. What do I need to type in the preamble? or more generally, how do I implement it in my document defaults?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I think you could just use a .tex file and `\input` that in the preamble. To save the preamble so it is used by default for all files, you can click on "Save as Document Defaults" in the Document > Settings dialog. A different approach would be to create a module. For more information on this, see Help > Customization.

Comment: To be clear, are you speaking of LyX macros or LaTeX macros? From your example it seems that you want the former.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on the definition, so assuming Lyx macros are a "composition" of math symbols and LaTex macros are more similar to ERT, then indeed the former, but I'm not sure whether my interpretation is correct. I want to add stuff such as integer symbols and vectors etc. by means of \Integers etc.

Comment: @Yoni Don't forget to notify the person your comment is targeted to. To do so, use the `@` key, followed by the user name. Otherwise, they will not know that you directed a comment at them (unless they happen to check back on their own but usually this does not happen).

Comment: @scottkosty Thanks for the tip. Also, are .tex files relevant for Lyx macros? If so, how do you make them and what is the correct formalism for macros?

Comment: @G.M. As said above, I think my intentions are Lyx macros.

Comment: @Yoni .tex files are files that contain LaTeX commands.

Comment: @scottkosty Can they be used to create Lyx math macros? and how do you write these macros in .tex files? because as I understand Lyx adds a certain level of masking that omits some raw Tex commands. I read in many threads that you can do all kinds of stuff, but what I'm asking is directions as to how to actually do these things. Is there a guide on how to actually write math macros in .tex files and use them in Lyx documents?

Comment: @Yoni you're asking good questions. I don't actually use macros myself so I don't know the answers. I suggest you read the section in Help > Math called "Math Macros".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how people do usually for math macros. (For text macros it would be entirely different and limited to defining custom insets or paragraph styles with layouts or modules.)

1. Define your macros as LyX macros as explained in `Help > Math > Math macros` in a file `macros.lyx`.
2. Use `Insert > File > Sub-document` to include `macros.lyx` at the beginning of your documents.

In practice, the macro file evolves with time so to avoid breaking the compilation or appearance of old documents you must create a new version (`macros2.lyx`...) before every major iteration.

Comment: Thanks, can this 'macros.lyx' be inserted through the LaTex Preamble in Document Settings as well?

Comment: It has to be included as a sub-document in main part of the document.

Comment: Well, good enough I suppose... Thank you both!